# Error: INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11 breaking my AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Is this error breaking my code? I get it in readystate 1.

Relevant HTML code:

```
<input type="button" value="Log In" onclick="login()" class="submit" />
```

Relevant Javascript:

```
function login() {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("headSpan").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "logIn.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send("usr=bob");
    }
```

logIn.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['usr'];
?>
```

Then, xmlhttp.responseText is "". If it's doing what I think it should be, I would get 'bob';

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: This error is defined as "If an attempt is made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable". Just FYI.

Comment: Which line does the error correspond to?

Comment: How would I find out? I've been using the Chrome Javascript console with just a breakpoint on if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200).

Comment: Oh, it doesn't give you a line?  Well, it's a pretty simple script; just place a breakpoint on all lines.

Comment: Also, all the AJAX examples I've ever seen put the `open()` before the `onreadystatechange`.  I seriously doubt that's the problem, but you never know...

Comment: See this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368857/invalid-state-err-dom-exception-11-when-i-execute-the-req-openget-url-true

Comment: Had seen it, it didn't help though. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
var params = "usr=bob";
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "logIn.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Apparently the request header doesn't automagically work for PHP always as I had assumed (and found no proof to dissuade me from that belief). Anyways, pretty simple solution, but frustrating nonetheless. Just for an extra bit of info: running WAMP (not the pre-built thingy, the acronym). Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3.3.